# find the number of functions such that $f : [0,1]\to [0,1]$ satisfying $|f(x) – f(y)|= |x – y|$ for all $(x, y)$ in $[0,1]$.

Tags: functions

The number of functions $f : [0,1]\to [0,1]$ satisfying $|f(x) – f(y)|= |x – y|$ for all $(x, y)$ in $[0,1]$ is?

$\frac {|f(x) – f(y)|}{|x – y|}= 1$

How to solve this?

Comment: Any assumption on $f$? For example, continuity?

Comment: @Virtuoz Nothing as such is provided by the question.

Comment: I am pretty sure to have seen this question asked on MSE already but I wasn't able to find it...

Comment: @Virtuoz Continuity follows from the definition of the function $|f(y+h)-f(y) | =|h|$ just let $h\to 0$.

Comment: @kingW3 Yeah, I see :) Didn't realize that from the first glance though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider
$$
|f(1) - f(0)| = 1-0 = 1.
$$
Since $f$ maps $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ we have only two cases. Either $f(1) = 1, f(0) = 0$ or $f(1)= 0, f(0) =1$.

Consider the first case $f(1) = 1, f(0) = 0$. Then
$$
f(x) = |f(x) - f(0)| = |x - 0| = x.
$$

Consider the second case $f(1) = 0, f(0) = 1$. Then
$$
f(x) = |f(x) - f(1)| = |x - 1| = 1 - x.
$$

So, eventually we have only two functions: $x$ and $1-x$.